# clingo compiler computing multiple values for #min

Tags: python, aggregate-functions, clingo

I’m having a basic issue whilst using python scripting in ASP / `clingo (Version 4+). I’ve reconstructed the problem with a minimal example, to illustrate the point. Obviously, in the example, I don’t need to use scripts. In my more complicated application, however, I do, whence I have artificially recreated the problem, in a more comprehendible fashion.

The issue is, that whilst calling an aggregate/optimisation, the compiler somehow does not register all the full predicate being used to index the values. Instead, it appears to successively compute the minimum and as a result, spits out all the values along the way. (See the output below: notice that the minimum goes from 59, to 19, then does not change to 29. This is highly sensitive of the order of `prg.ground`calls in the `#script (python)` part of the code.)

This is highly undesirable, and I would like to know how to avoid this problem. I. e., **how can I amend the below code** still utilising a python-script (potentially modified), so that the correct model is computed. (In the example, obviously, the solution to the predicate `min_sel_weight/1` is `min_sel_weight(19)`with no further values.

*The Programme.*

```
weight("ant",3). weight("bat",53). weight("cat",19). weight("dot",13). weight("eel",29).

#script (python)
import gringo;
def main(prg):
    prg.ground([('base', [])]);
    prg.ground([('sel', ['bat'])]);
    prg.ground([('sel', ['cat'])]);
    prg.ground([('sel', ['eel'])]);
    prg.solve();
#end.

%% call python-script, to select certain objects.
#program sel(t). sel(t).

%% compute minimum of weights of selected objects:
min_sel_weight(X) :- weight(_,X), #min {XX : weight(OBJ,XX),sel(OBJ)} = X.

#show sel/1. #show min_sel_weight/1.
```

*Calling* `clingo 0 myprogramme.lp` *I obtain the following output:*

> ```
> clingo version 4.5.4
> Reading from myprogramme.lp
> Solving...
> Answer: 1
>     sel("bat")
>     min_sel_weight(53)
>     sel("cat")
>     min_sel_weight(19)
>     sel("eel")
> SATISFIABLE
>
> Models       : 1    
> Calls        : 1
> Time         : 0.096s (Solving: 0.00s 1st Model: 0.00s Unsat: 0.00s)
> CPU Time     : 0.040s
> ```

Comment: Note: similar problems occur with `#max` and `#sum`. Whatever the solution is (if there exists one), it needs to be adaptable to the situation, in which these other aggregates are computed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
% instance
weight("ant",3). weight("bat",53). weight("cat",19). weight("dot",13). weight("eel",29).


% Assuming you will get certain selected objects like this:
selected("cat"). selected("bat"). selected("eel"). %this will be python generated

% encoding
selectedWeight(OBJ, XX):- weight(OBJ,XX), selected(OBJ).
1{min_sel_weight(X)}1 :- selectedWeight(_,X), #min {XX : selectedWeight(OBJ,XX),selected(OBJ)} = X.

#show min_sel_weight/1.
```

Output:

[image]